# Convert Color Spaces in Pillow / PIL

Tags: opencv, python-imaging-library, color-space

Right now I am converting an image from `YCrCb` to `RGB` using OpenCV:

```
cv2.cvtColor(arr, cv2.COLOR_YCR_CB2RGB)
```

Is there a function in Pillow / PIL to perform this same color conversion. At the very least I would like to perform the color conversion without needing OpenCV.

I tried the following:

```
def _rgb( xxx ):
    y, cb, cr = xxx
    r = y                          + 1.402   * ( cr - 128 )
    g = y -  .34414 * ( cb - 128 ) -  .71414 * ( cr - 128 )
    b = y + 1.772   * ( cb - 128 )
    return r, g, b

np.apply_along_axis( _rgb, 2, arr.astype( np.float32 ) ).astype( np.uint8 )
```

and it is very slow and does not quite work.

Comment: If you're reading this question, you may be interested also in pillow's ability to interprete a numpy array as YCbCr values when converting to a pillow-image. This is done via the argument "mode" of Image.fromarray (https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.fromarray).

Answer (score 1):

### Conversion per-se

YCrCb-Colorspace conversion to RGB-Colorspace states:

```
  R  = Y                            + 1.402   * ( Cr - 128 )
  G  = Y   - 0.34414 * ( Cb - 128 ) - 0.71414 * ( Cr - 128 )
  B  = Y   + 1.772   * ( Cb - 128 )
```

**<sub>Nota Bene 1:</sub>**
**`openCV`** sources document it's conversion process to be performed with different coefs than the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV based on ITU-R Recommendation BT-709, resp. BT-601:

```
  R  = Y                               + 1.403   * ( Cr - delta )
  G  = Y   - 0.344   * ( Cb - delta )  - 0.714   * ( Cr - delta )
  B  = Y   + 1.773   * ( Cb - delta )
```

where

```
  delta =   128   # for  8-bit images             CV_8U,
  #       32768   # for 16-bit images             CV_16U,
  #           0.5 # for floating-point images     CV_32F.
```

**<sub>Nota Bene 2: [ref. below]</sub>**

---

### Efficient implementation

Using vectorised mode, `numpy` can help with potential further acceleration speedup from JIT-compilation from `numba`:

```
import numpy as np
import numba

@numba.jit
def translateYCrCb2RGB( a3DMatrixOfUINT8_YCrCb ):          # naive type-checking & no exception handling

    a3DMatrixOfUINT8_RGB        = np.zeros(   a3DMatrixOfUINT8_YCrCb.shape,
                                              dtype = np.uint8
                                              )

    a3DMatrixOfUINT8_RGB[:,:,0] =             a3DMatrixOfUINT8_YCrCb[:,:,0]            \
                                + 1.402   * ( a3DMatrixOfUINT8_YCrCb[:,:,1] - 128 )


    a3DMatrixOfUINT8_RGB[:,:,1] =             a3DMatrixOfUINT8_YCrCb[:,:,0]            \
                                - 0.34414 * ( a3DMatrixOfUINT8_YCrCb[:,:,2] - 128 )    \
                                - 0.71414 * ( a3DMatrixOfUINT8_YCrCb[:,:,1] - 128 )

    a3DMatrixOfUINT8_RGB[:,:,2] =             a3DMatrixOfUINT8_YCrCb[:,:,0]            \
                                + 1.772   * ( a3DMatrixOfUINT8_YCrCb[:,:,2] - 128 )


    return( a3DMatrixOfUINT8_RGB )
```

Further acceleration tricks may help at a cost of a larger memory footprint or destructive handling of the mutable original YCrCb-matrix

### Pre-sliced approach

```
@numba.jit
def translateYCrCb2RGB( Y__slice,   # YCrCb_ORIGINAL[:,:,0], # ... asView
                        Cr_slice,   # YCrCb_ORIGINAL[:,:,1], # ... asView
                        Cb_slice    # YCrCb_ORIGINAL[:,:,2]  # ... asView
                        ):          # naive type-checking & no exception handling
    return( np.dstack( ( Y__slice                                + 1.402   * ( Cr_slice - 128 ),
                         Y__slice - 0.34414 * ( Cb_slice - 128 ) - 0.71414 * ( Cr_slice - 128 ),
                         Y__slice + 1.772   * ( Cb_slice - 128 )
                         )          # .dstack consumes aTUPLE
                       )
            )
```

---

### Conventions need not match

```
def getCvFromPIL( PILpic ):
    return np.array( PILpic.getdata(),            # .getdata()
                     dtype = np.uint8             # .uint8 type-enforced
                     ).reshape( ( PILpic.size[1], # .reshape x
                                  PILpic.size[0], #          y
                                  3               #          z-depth
                                  )               # aTUPLE
                                )[:,:,::-1]       # RGB c-reverse -> to BGR as cv2 standard representation
```

---

### 2)

[From `openCV` sources one may read about implemented precision of coefs](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp):

```
template<typename _Tp> struct YCrCb2RGB_f
{
    typedef _Tp channel_type;

    YCrCb2RGB_f(int _dstcn, int _blueIdx, const float* _coeffs)
        : dstcn(_dstcn), blueIdx(_blueIdx)
    {
        static const float coeffs0[] = {1.403f, -0.714f, -0.344f, 1.773f};
        memcpy(coeffs, _coeffs ? _coeffs : coeffs0, 4*sizeof(coeffs[0]));
    }
    void operator()(const _Tp* src, _Tp* dst, int n) const
    {
        int dcn = dstcn, bidx = blueIdx;
        const _Tp delta = ColorChannel<_Tp>::half(), alpha = ColorChannel<_Tp>::max();
        float C0 = coeffs[0], C1 = coeffs[1], C2 = coeffs[2], C3 = coeffs[3];
        n *= 3;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i += 3, dst += dcn)
        {
            _Tp Y = src[i];
            _Tp Cr = src[i+1];
            _Tp Cb = src[i+2];

            _Tp b = saturate_cast<_Tp>(Y + (Cb - delta)*C3);
            _Tp g = saturate_cast<_Tp>(Y + (Cb - delta)*C2 + (Cr - delta)*C1);
            _Tp r = saturate_cast<_Tp>(Y + (Cr - delta)*C0);

            dst[bidx] = b; dst[1] = g; dst[bidx^2] = r;
            if( dcn == 4 )
                dst[3] = alpha;
        }
    }
    int dstcn, blueIdx;
    float coeffs[4];
};
```

Comment: That does not seem to work right. `np.all(cv2.cvtColor(arr, cv2.COLOR_YCR_CB2RGB) == translateYCrCb2RGB(arr))` yields `False`.

Comment: @AlexRothberg did you check **`dtype == np.uint8`** a-priori? Next be also aware that the YCrCb-RGB conversion is aproximate and precision matters in `==` matches.

Comment: The `==` was a bad example. I am rendering the image and I get a noticable  differently colored image than what I get from opencv.

Comment: You may know, Alex, that your first objection above is not principally correct. Your code calls **`openCV`** function `.cvtColor()` to process an array **`arr`** ( which means it is in `openCV` internally c-reversed  **`BGR`** layout, which is not the case of your request to process RGB-aligned `numpy.array` as coded into the solution example in **`translateYCrCb2RGB()`**

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I have specified to OpenCV to use `RGB` rather than `BGR`. To verify I also compared your posted solution against `Image.fromarray(cv2.cvtColor(arr, cv2.COLOR_YCR_CB2BGR))` and likewise it does not match.

Comment: Check PIL-data model, dtype, BGR-layout difference and coefs difference, as all documented above. No more magic behind & **enjoy the StackOverflow**.